# strange `int_of_string` call?

Tags: ocaml

The following code snippet is from ocsigen source. I donot understand "int_of_string" called with two arguments:

```
 try
    let dppos = String.index ss':'
        and len = String.length ss in                     
        let host = String.sub ss 0 dppos                  
        and port =                                        
            match String.sub ss (dppos+1) ((len - dppos) - 1) with
                "*" -> None
                | p -> Some (int_of_string "host" p)
             in host, port                                                           
  with                                                
      | Not_found -> ss, None
      | Failure _ ->                                    
          raise (Config_file_error "bad port number")
```

I test it in toplevel, it reports error normally .

Sincerely!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note at the top of that file:

```
let blah_of_string f tag s =
  try
    f (String.remove_spaces s 0 ((String.length s) -1))
  with Failure _ -> raise (Ocsigen_config.Config_file_error
                             ("While parsing <"^tag^"> - "^s^
                                " is not a valid value."))

let int_of_string = blah_of_string int_of_string
let float_of_string = blah_of_string float_of_string
```

i.e. it's not `Pervasives.int_of_string` at all!